# difference between Clone in desktop and zip download

Tags: git, android-studio, clone

What is the difference between **Downloading** and **Cloning** a project? I cloned a project, it became a repository. Did my own project on my desktop become a new project for the community?

And, what does it mean when Android studio tells me:

> Unregistered VCS root directory. The directory is under Git, but it is note registered in the settings.

Please don't answer me telling that I have a Git project in my project, I know that. I just would like to know what does it mean?

Comment: I used the git command in the shell to clone the project.

Answer (score 5):

"clone" uses git software on your computer to download the source code and it's entire version history.

"download zip" creates a zip file of just the current version of the source code for you to download - the project history is not included.

Comment: okay, thanks. But the git clone on my desktop is shared? If I change the clone, it is affected a clone that others can use? 
And, i'm in the history version of the project?

Answer (score 0):

**Downloading** fetches only the current version of the repository.

**Cloning** downloads the whole repository with all its metadata: history, branches, tags etc. As mentioned in another answer, you need working Git in your machine for cloning a repository and for maintaining it locally.

> Did my own project on my desktop become a new project for the community?

You cloned it *from* cloud *to* your computer, right? So the answer is **No**. You would need to create a new project on the server and clone *from* your machine *into* it.